# Build custom ac-dc power supply- ground wire

Tags: power-supply

I am building a ac-dc power supply and am wondering what I should do with the ground wire from the ac wall plug. Do I ground it to the casing on the transformer? Or should I just leave it unused? Should I tie all the dc grounds with the ac ground wire?

Answer (score 1):

The best option in my opinion is:

1) Connect the chassis pin to the power supply cabinet.

2) Provide a chassis jack in the front panel of the PS.

In this way, depending on the use, you can decide to short the (-) output, or even the (+) output to the chassis as needed for each application.

Professional power supplies provide a metallic bridge to connect (+) or (-) to chassis (and chassis as a third jack).

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

- It's a good idea to ground the transformer frame at least. This will ensure that any bolts holding the transformer into the case are earthed and can't be a hazard on the outside.
- Obviously, if the case is metal it should be grounded too.
- Grounding the DC is optional and depends on your circuit requirements. Sometimes a floating DC is required. Sometimes a ground-referenced supply is required. Edit your question to explain the application if further detail is required.